# Selecting n-th child of an <ol> within a div

Tags: jquery, click, html-lists, css-selectors

I am trying to make an image slider, which slides images according to which `<li>` is selected within an `<ol>`. If second bullet is clicked then -> change colour of background -> slide to image 2.

This is what I tried:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {

        gallery_image_slider();
        slider();
    });

    function slider() {

        $('project_selector>ol>li:nth-child(1)').click(function() { 

            $('project_selector>ol>li:nth-child(1)').css('background' : 'black');

    }  );


<div class="projects">
            <h1>Current Projects</h1>

        <div class="current_projects" align="center">

            <div class="projects_gallery" align="center">

                <table align="center">
                     <tr>
                        <th>
                            <div class="project_desc_1">
                            Project Description 1
                            </div>

                            <div class="project_desc_2">
                            Project Description 2
                            </div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <th>
                            <div class="slide"><img src="./images/blivori.png"/ id="project1"></div>
                            <div class="slide"><img src="./images/blivori.png"/ id="project2"></div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <th>
                            <ol class='project_selector'>
                                <li></li>
                                <li></li>
                                <li></li>
                            </ol>
                        </th>
                    </tr>           

                     <tr>
                        <th>
                            <label id="description1">Description 1</label>
                            <label id="description2">Description 2</label>
                        </th>
                    </tr>   
                </table>

            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when selecting a class with jQuery, you need to prepend a period (`.`) to its name, like this:

```
$('.project_selector')
```

Second of all, I can see that you have no `<ol>` tags within your `project_selector` list.
I'm not sure what you want to attain by `li:nth-child(1)`, but if your intent is to select the first `<li>`, then you're to use the `.eq()` method and specify its first argument the index of the `<li>` that interests you, zero-based.

```
function slider() {
   $(document).on('click', '.project_selector > li:eq(0)', function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your code and your question i'm confused, but if your trying to get your code to work

```
function slider() {

    $('.project_selector li').click(function() { 

        $(this).css({'background' : 'black'});

   });
}
```